# Laravel eloquent to json

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent, vue.js

I'm using vue.js in Laravel. This is my table structure:

```
Article  
id
name
description

Location 
id
place


article_location (pivot table)
--fields--
id
article_id (foreign key)
location_id (foreign key)
```

I would like to convert this to json:

```
article.place
article.description
location.place
```

What's the right way of doing this with eloquent?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <data list="{{ $location->artikel()->toJson() //<-something like this? }}"></data>
        </div>

        <template id="ln-data">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="value in list">
                    @{{ value.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </template>

        <script>
        Vue.config.debug = true;

        Vue.component('data', {
            template: '#ln-data',
            props:['list'],

            created() {
                this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
            }
        })

        new Vue({
            el: 'body'
        });
        </script>
```

My controller:

```
$location = location::all(); return view('locationproducts')->with('location',$location);
```

location model:

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\article','article_location');
}
```

Error:

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81: Method article does not
>   exist. (View:
>   /home/vagrant/Code/project/resources/views/locationproducts.blade.php)

Comment: So I get an error of maximum function nesting:100 reached when I simply put {{$a_collection}} in the template. So I just called the toJson method in the controller and passed it as a variable. Another thing here is that you should use single quotes after "<data list="  since the the JSON string will be in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find API of the Model class at this URL : https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html You can see that the function toJson already exist.

You have some a typo in your html you writed "$location->artikel()->toJson()" instead of "$location->article()->toJson()" maybe this is your problem.